# Spell Combat and Halfling Sling Staff/Thrown Weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e

My question is pretty straightforward. The Magus ability spellstrike reads:

> To use this ability, the magus must have one hand free (even if the spell being cast does not have somatic components), while wielding a light or one-handed melee weapon in the other hand. As a full-round action, he can make all of his attacks with his melee weapon at a –2 penalty and can also cast any spell from the magus spell list with a casting time of 1 standard action (any attack roll made as part of this spell also takes this penalty).

Can the magus use spell combat with a Halfling Sling Staff (which is a melee weapon) to make ranged attacks? Similarly if the magus is wielding a dagger can they throw it as part of spell combat?

Note: I am aware of the existence of ranged magus archtypes.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

According to the [Equipment](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/equipment.html) listing

> Melee and Ranged Weapons: Melee weapons are used for making melee attacks, **though some of them can be thrown as well**. Ranged weapons are thrown weapons or projectile weapons **that are not effective in melee**.

(Emphasis mine)

According to this, no matter how you use the dagger it retains its identity as a **Melee Weapon** and fits the Magus' Spellstrike wording. This would also extend to any melee weapon that is thrown, regardless of it has a range increment or not (though they would take all appropriate penalties).

This is, of course, somewhat unintuitive, especially when considering that there are archetypes with thrown weapons for the magus. Don't be surprised if a GM overrules this interpretation, or if a future FAQ comes up to shoot it down.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if someone find something contradictory elsewhere in the rules/errata/FAQ about this topic. I couldn't find anything, but I've fared poorly with searching those things before.